# How to package 3rd party .so with AOSP image

Tags: android, package, android-source, android-8.0-oreo, iso-image

I'm trying to deploy fastRTPS library I've build with my AOSP ( Oreo x86 ) image.
I have library located in 
./device/generic/xchg/rtps/lib/x86_64/
This directory contain only 2 files:
Android.mk
libfastrtps.so

I ran 
mmm device/generic/xchg/rtps/lib/x86_64
to make
my library appearing in 
./out/target/product/x86_64/system/lib64

after that I trying to make an iso image:
make iso_img -j6 TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG=kernel/arch/x86/configs/android-x86_64_defconfig  USE_SQUASHFS=0

But resulting image does not contain my library ( verified via adb shell command line )

Content of Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfastrtps
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfastrtps.so
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 0):

add your library to "PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \ libfastrtps.so" in your device.mk file